# Is Necrophagia The Act Of Eating Dead Animal Flesh Only?

Tags: meaning

Does necrophagia apply only to consuming animal flesh, or also human flesh?

Comment: Curious to know what you found when you looked in a dictionary.

Comment: The New Oxford American Dictionary in my Mac had no entry. Dictionary.com vaguely stated "feeding on corpses". I suppose that applies to both human and animal—which I surmise means Brian is correct.

Comment: Looks like he's your man!

Answer (score 3):

Human flesh too, yes. OED s.v. *necrophage:*

> An organism, esp. an insect, that feeds on dead bodies or tissue. Also in extended use.

And of course insects do feed on dead human flesh—hence [maggot therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggot_therapy) and the profession of [forensic entomologist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_entomology).